# STContains returns points OUTSIDE polygon. Should return points INSIDE polygon

Tags: python, sql-server, geospatial, spatial

I have this very long jupyter notebook

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


#Setting Environment
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, Marker, Polygon
import pyodbc
import json

#Getting ODBC Connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=<<SERVER>>;DATABASE=<<DATABASE>>;UID=<<USER>>;PWD=<<PWD>>;TrustServerCertificate=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#center function
def centroid(vertexes):
     _x_list = [vertex [0] for vertex in vertexes]
     _y_list = [vertex [1] for vertex in vertexes]
     _len = len(vertexes)
     _x = sum(_x_list) / _len
     _y = sum(_y_list) / _len
     return(_x, _y)


# In[2]:


#set TBL1
TBL1=9543


# In[17]:


#getting Polygon GEOJSON
cursor.execute(f"SELECT geography.ReorientObject().ToString()  FROM DB1..TBL1 WHERE id = {TBL1}")
top = 0
bottom = 90
left = 0
right = -90 
geography = cursor.fetchval()
geography = geography.replace('POLYGON ((','').replace('))', '').split(', ')
nodes = []
for node in geography:
    node = node.split(' ')
    top = float(node[1]) if float(node[1]) > top else top
    bottom = float(node[1]) if float(node[1]) < bottom else bottom
    left = float(node[0]) if float(node[0]) < left else left
    right = float(node[0]) if float(node[0]) > right else right
    nodes.append((float(node[1]),float(node[0])))
nodes


# In[18]:


print(top, bottom)
print(left, right)


# In[24]:


#getting Points
cursor.execute(f"""
    select TBL2.[TBL2_ID]
          ,TBL2.LAT
          ,TBL2.LONG
          ,TBL1.[User]
          ,TBL1.[ID]
          from DB1..TBL2, DB1..[TBL1]
          where 1 = TBL1.[geography].ReorientObject().STContains(geography::Point(TBL2.LAT, TBL2.LONG, 4326))
          and TBL1.id =  {TBL1}
          and TBL2.LAT between {bottom} and {top}
          and TBL2.LONG between {left} and {right};""")
points = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(points))
print(points[0:10])


# In[25]:


center = centroid(nodes)
zoom = 12
m = Map(basemap=basemaps.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik, zoom=zoom, center=center)

poly = Polygon(
    locations=nodes,
    color="green",
    fill_color="green"
)
m.add_layer(poly)

for point in points:
    marker = Marker(location=(point[1], point[2]), title=str(point[0]), draggable=False)
    m.add_layer(marker)

m





# In[ ]:
```

Line 17 returns:

```
[(40.71601696448174, -74.00765417724092),
 (40.71839144945969, -74.01160238891084),
 (40.72613233284465, -74.00872706084688),
 (40.72525421067396, -74.00568007140596),
 (40.723888219823266, -74.00619505553682),
 (40.71900945220738, -73.99632452636202),
 (40.71507365242344, -73.99902819304903),
 (40.718554082317965, -74.00559424071749),
 (40.71601696448174, -74.00765417724092)]
```

Line 17 returns over 4000 points, however, the last line shows the map that has all the points OUTSIDE the polygon with no reason.  We added the clause `ReorientObject()`, but it looks like we are still seeing the bad runs.

See image below:

[image]

What am I missing?  The intent is only to get the points inside.

Comment: Orientation? Ref: [Orientation of spatial data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/polygon#orientation-of-spatial-data)

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might have your coordinate axis reversed. If this package is like most, the coordinates are typically `(x, y)` which for geography would be `(longitude, latitude)`. It looks like your data is showing `(latitude, longitude)`. (Based on Manhatten New York being roughly in the vicinity of 40.7N 74W.)  Swapping the axis would also effectively reverse the sense of clockwise vs counter-clockwise when defining polygons..

Comment: Why are you reorienting object? Wouldn't it invert the geom so that everything *else* becomes it? 
In that case the STWithin is correct, since your geom is everything *but* the inner polygon.

Comment: I'd look at using `gdal` - http://gdal.org to handle the spatial operations to save doing it your self

Comment: ok.  lots of good genius...apologize for the late reply.  We were reorientating due to an earlier question talking about this same subject.  I was told my polygons are out of sequence.